# My code is dropping all PHP sessions after logging

Tags: php, session

Once my users log in and verify themselves I am sending my adimninstrators to an activity page. This inital page shows session values when I dump the sessions. However when I move to any other page in my site I lose the session values.

I am setting my pages by including the classes in the header file. I calling session start (`if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }`) at the top of each file in the site. I have nothing within my code that will cause my session to be destroyed.

when the user is being authenticated, i am using this snippet of PHP

```php
<?php require_once('includes/init.php'); ?>
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
            require 'auth_login.php';
        } elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { 
            require 'register.php';
        }
    }
?>
```

when they submit the form, they are sent to auth_login, and the successful login/verification code looks like this:

```php
        if ($_POST['code'] == $users->auth_code) {

            $_SESSION['logged_in']  = 'true';
            $_SESSION['id']         = $users->id;

            redirect("/admin/activity.php");

        }
```

This is the content of my init file:

```php
if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("functions.php");
require_once("config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
```

My functions file:

```php
<?php

    function classAutoLoader($class){

        $class = strtolower($class);
        $the_path = "includes/{$class}.php";
        if(is_file($the_path) && !class_exists($class)){
            require_once($the_path);
        } else {
            die ("File, {$class} does not exist");
        }

    }

    spl_autoload_register('classAutoLoader');

    function redirect($location){
        header("Location:{$location}");
    }
?>
```

My config file:

```php
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'XXX');
define('DB_USER', 'XXX');
define('DB_PASS', 'XXX');
define('DB_NAME', 'XXX');
?>
```

My database class

```php
    class Database{
        public $connection;
        function __construct(){
            $this->open_db_connection();
        }
        public function open_db_connection(){
            $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if ($this->connection->connect_errno){
                die("Database connection failed ". $this->connection->connect_errno);
            }
        }
        public function query($sql){
            $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
            $this->confirm_query($result);
            return $result;
        }
        private function confirm_query($result){
            if (!$result){
                die("Query Failed". $this->connection->error);
            }
        }
        public function escape_string($string){
            $escaped_string = $this->connection->real_escape_string($string);
            return $escaped_string;
        }
        public function the_insert_id(){
            return $this->connection->insert_id;
        }
    }
    $database = new Database();
```

When my user lands on activity.php, i am using these 2 snippets

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(session_status());
echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

There I get my 2 values in the session dump and I get int(2) session status.  When i hit any other page in my directory I lose the sessions in the dump, but i still see a int(2) for my status.

I am leaning towards thinking that my issue exist within the htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|processes|paypal-ipn/)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

All traffic except a directory is having the file extensions striped. Could that be what is causing my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }`? Why not just `session_start()`?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot recall. It has been edited some many times tying to fix this issue. I  think i just want to test it differently.

Comment: Well, that conditional means you don't call `session_start` if the user has a session ID, which means none of your session code will work, because `session_start` must *always* be called. So I presume it's at least part of your troubles.

Comment: I see your point. However, would i still be getting int(2) for session_status?

Comment: No clue. Remove the pointless conditional and see!

Comment: i get the same result

Comment: `All traffic except a directory is having the file extensions striped. Could that be what is causing my problem.`. No. As long as the file is run as a PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

## Work In Progress:

*I'm afraid I'm going to have to go, but we have proven that the session saves correctly and can be read from the same file, as is written to. So if the other files are in another folder then there may be some folder specific PHP.ini settings messing up the session reading? I think the issue does appear to be outside the scope of what you've put in your question, but that is not to place blame, simply that it's more complex to establish what's going on.*

---

> I have nothing within my code that will cause my session to be destroyed.

Then this means that sessions are not being started, so the session data is unavailable to PHP.

> I do have session start at the top of my init file.

So the next step is to `var_dump($_SESSION);` *immediately after you start the session*, like so:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

var_dump($_SESSION);

require_once("functions.php");
...
```

And let us know what this outputs? Are the sessions empty or are they full of stuff at the point of time the page loads?

---

> I do not know how to access the sessions directory on my server

You need to load the `phpinfo` or the `php.ini` file and see where it says:

session.savepath . This is where sessions are stored. Once you know this you can open that folder, and find the session file, usually `sess_<session_id value>` and see if any data is being *written* to the session.

---

## Update 3:

Please try this adjusted code:

```
    if ($_POST['code'] == $users->auth_code) {

        $_SESSION['logged_in']  = 'true';
        $_SESSION['id']         = $users->id;

        session_write_close();
        session_start();
        error_log(print_r($_SESSION,true));

        redirect("/admin/activity.php");
```

This will write to the session, close the session and then open the session and save the contents to the Error Log file. You should be using error logs far more than screen displays.

**Result:**

> The error log shows me this. [02-Aug-2019 21:10:50 UTC] Array ( [logged_in] => true [id] => 1 ) [02-Aug-2019 21:10:50 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined index: email in /home/linepickleadmin/public_html/admin/auth_verify.php on line 34

Comment: I do have session start at the top of my init file. I do not know how to access the sessions directory on my server using the Cpanel. SoI cannot verify as you suggested.

Comment: @dlavely I have updated my answer. Please let me know your outcome

Comment: on first page past my login: 
array(2) {
  ["logged_in"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

on the second page i hit, i get an empty array and no error messages

Comment: I found my savepath, but i am not sure how to access using the Cpanel. My directories are limit

Comment: @dlavely please can you update your code in your question and show where/how you actually use the data in the session? Where you *read* it? Thank you.

Comment: I can, but i have restricted access and can only access the site, nothing above it. I do not have root access

Comment: @dlavely are you limited to `/public_html` or can you access `/home/<accountname>/...` ?

Comment: Can you access the `PHP ini editor` menu item in CPanel?

Comment: The error log shows me this.
[02-Aug-2019 21:10:50 UTC] Array
(
    [logged_in] => true
    [id] => 1
)

[02-Aug-2019 21:10:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /home/linepickleadmin/public_html/admin/auth_verify.php on line 34

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197410/discussion-between-dlavely-and-martin).

Comment: That's great. Thanks. That shows that the session is being written to and is being read from in the same file. Are the files that read the `$_SESSION` in a different folder? to the `auth_login` page?